# WSO2 ESB Proxy Service TCP Transport Timeout settings

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a TCP transport based proxy service that is listening for connections through the ESB version 4.8.0.  I have some clients that are sending to the service that seem to be timing out or closing the TCP socket connection after 63 seconds for some, and 15 seconds for others.

We are working to determine whether the issue is manifesting on the ESB side or the client side.

Are their connection specific settings for TCP sockets on the ESB side?  Either through the proxy parameters or through the axis2.xml config file?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MyCoolService"
       transports="tcp"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <dbreport>
            <!-- MySQL Insert statement code -->
         </dbreport>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" category="DEBUG"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="enableMTOM">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6245</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/MyCoolService/services/MyService/policies/RMPolicy"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Can you post the proxy service xml source? and are you using default endpoint configuration parameters?

Comment: Just posted.. Yes, using default endpoint parameters